# Got +2 rep for nothing

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

I was looking through my rep changes, and I noticed +2 credited 5 minutes ago for [Is it possible to automatically log in to link using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201974/is-it-possible-to-automatically-log-in-to-link-using-javascript), but I didn't change anything, and the answer doesn't seem to have anything new on it. Could someone please explain the rep change I got?

Answer (score 6):

Your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1701772) to the question was approved. Thus you got +2 rep for it.

Comment: Must have missed the approval, I read the denied one from earlier, and left it alone after that.

Answer (score 0):

You did indeed change something; you [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6880489) to the question, which was reviewed by other users and approved.

Approved suggestions are rewarded by a small amount of rep to encourage everybody to improve posts whenever they're able.

The full explanation is on Meta.SE: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)